# How to make a Label stay centered when moved?

Tags: vb.net, label

So I just want the text in a label to always stay centered if it's moved.

Am I missing a property or something?

This is the normal text:

> ```
>             Description
> ```

How it looks like when changed:

> ```
>             The button is used for ...
> ```

How I want it to be:

> ```
>       The button is used for ...
> ```

Comment: What does the html of your label and the container it's inside of look like?

Comment: I don't understand ... i'm new to programming in VB ...

Comment: Show your code.  WinForms, WPF, ASP.Net, etc.  How is this label moving?

Comment: I have no code to show, it's just a label and when i click a button it changes the text to something random, but the problem is the text won't stay centered

Comment: I assume you are using Visual Studio.  Did you create a Win Forms project, an ASP.NET Web Application project?  It makes a difference.

Comment: Ugh.  If WinForms, turn AutoSize to false, TextAlign to TopCenter.

Comment: ... or `MiddleCenter` =D

Comment: I said in the title VB, but it was edited :( Sorry. Thanks LarsTech it works now.

Comment: For future reference, you can use VB in WinForm, WPF, ASP.Net, etc, so it's not enough to say just VB, we need to know the platform too when you are referring to graphical controls.

Comment: Sorry :( As i said i'm just starting. Thank you all.